# Can someone please explain this political cartoon?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, cartoon

I have always enjoyed the political cartons at https://www.usnews.com/cartoons/donald-trump

However, this one has me stumped. Can someone please explain it? It's not hat I don't find it humorous, or disagree with it. I simply do not understand what it is trying to convey.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but something about the lines of "Donald Trump is drowning(*) because he has not been up to his roles as POTUS." Here drowning could either refer to his isolation, the public perception of him or the future legal charges he might face. In any case, this cartoon seems to me more as it is trying to convey a feeling (failure?) than an statement.

Comment: The previous and next day cartoon from the same author are a bit more obvious: "coup coup" and the 25th. https://www.creators.com/features/gary-markstein I guess cartoonists run out of poignant stuff when they have to dish out one cartoon every day... but I agree with SJuan that Trump drowning is probably the idea there.

Comment: Trump drowning? Aha, now I see it. Possibly also bursting through?  I am still at a loss

Comment: Looking at the lines (or curves) added to the seal, it could also be Trump swallowed by a black hole, which is often depicted as a funnel-shaped piece of space time. E.g. https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-resources/how-big-is-a-black-hole/

Comment: @Jens: that might have something to do with social media bans of him then,  but that doesn't quite explain why the seal is in the background... The date corresponds though as Twitter banned him sometime on the 8th and the cartoon was penned on the 9th.

Comment: The presidency, the institution behind it and its traditions, is bigger than trump, and consuming him.